# Objective C Autorelease in a loop with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: objective-c, loops, autorelease, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to format an array of numbers to display in an array of CCLabelTTFs in a loop.  NSNumberFormatter returns an autorelease object. I am not quite sure how I should be handling the memory management here.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the problem I'm trying to figure out:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *tempString;

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    tempString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NumberArray[i]]];
    CCLabelTTFArray[i] = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] initWithString: tempString fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:10.0f];
    [tempString release];
}

[formatter release];
```

Comment: You do not need to call `[tempString release];`, that's all. The run loop will "autorelease" the objects for you some time *after* your method completes.

Comment: I thought there might be a problem since I change the tempString pointer and so I lose the pointer to that object.  I thought it might be causing a memory leak since a the end of the function it will autorelease tempString but not all of the previous allocations of tempString.  I didn't mean to put the [tempString release], my mistake.

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your last comment.

Comment: Why do you use a C array instead of NSArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to call `[tempString release];`: the run loop will "autorelease" the objects for you some time *after* your method completes. With short-running loops (such as yours, that have only ten iterations) there is nothing else to worry about. For loops with thousands of iterations, you may consider adding an [Autorelease Pool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).

> I thought it might be causing a memory leak since a the end of the function it will autorelease tempString but not all of the previous allocations of tempString

Each invocation of the `stringFromNumber:` method adds its return value to autorelease pool, so no matter how many times you loop executes, all returned strings will be autoreleased.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the straight forward response.  Everything I have read up until this point hasn't been clear about how autorelease objects are tracked.